# Obtaining Cpu And Memory Information Inside a System Call

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to achieve CPU and Memory usage information of current process, inside a system call.
I can get current process name, pid and uid by using :

```
current->comm //process name
current->pid //process id
current_uid() //uid
```

but that seems to be all.(I am using kernel 3.2.0-24-generic)

As I have seen from [Memory usage of current process in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558402/memory-usage-of-current-process-in-c), reading(vfs_read) and parsing `/proc/pid/status` seems to be the only option to get memory and cpu usage.

Is there a better way to obtain this information, or am I on the right track?

I also test my code as a kernel module first, since both system calls and kernel modules are running in kernel space. Is that also bad approach?

Comment: There are many other interesting files under `/proc/` in particular `/proc/self/stat` and `/proc/self/maps` and `/proc/self/statm` etc; you could also use `clock_gettime` or `getrusage` or `times` or `gettimeofday` system calls ...

Comment: Thanks for answers, stat, maps and statm will be helpful if i try to parse values.But i could not manage to use getrusage since I do not have sys/resource.h and can not find it anywhere.

Comment: You probably need to install appropriate developer packages, like `libc6-dev` or something similar [details are distribution specific], to get `<sys/resource.h>` header file.

Answer (score 0):

`current->mm` is the place where all memory information is stored.
`current->mm->mmap` is a list of memory mappings for the process, so you can iterate it and see what you find there.

`current->utime` and `current->stime` may be useful for getting CPU information.