# how to find size /memory space occupied by a "process"

Tags: c++, c, linux

I was asked to write a c/cpp program to find size of any process in an interview. can any one tell me how this could be achieve ?

p.s.- before marking the que as duplicate - plz read it carefully : I have asked how to find via **c/cpp program** not just with any unix/linux shell command

Comment: Use [`pmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap)?

Comment: There is already a similar question [here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558402/memory-usage-of-current-process-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage). But keep in mind that it is not implemented on all systems.

Or by reading the `/proc/[pid]/statm`

Otherwise, try one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process) (command line options).

Answer (score 1):

It's not part of standard C++ and thus depends on the operating system.

On linux for example that is done by accessing [`/proc` filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).

Another option is of course to just call a system command like `ps` and parse its output (that is is what I'd do in a Python script).

Being able to interpret the numbers you can get is however another non trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
size <executable>
```

Output

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1361623    1984    2708 1366315  14d92b <executable>
```

It shows text, data, bss and total size